# how to change QToolButton opacity using QPainter?

Tags: qt, qpainter

I use `QToolButton` and according to some conditions I want to change the opacity of my `QToolButton` or specially icon of it, whether using `QPainter` or any other way.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to change the opacity of the icon and not the `QToolButton`?

Comment: In my `QToolButton` I just have an icon and it doesn't matter to change the opacity of `QToolButton` or just it's icon. If there's a way to change the opacity of the icon, it would be helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) on your `QToolButton`, or you can repaint your icon with different opacity. Use [`QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) composition mode to reduce the alpha.

This is a little example of how to use `QPainter` to do that:

```
QImage image(":/img/myimage.png");
QPainter p;
p.begin(&image);
p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
p.fillRect(image.rect(), QColor(0, 0, 0, 50));
p.end();
```